DeviceActivityReport not showing report data to main app
I am getting this error when I try to show device activity report view by this DeviceActivityReport(appsContext, filter: filter)
Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.
I have taken access by this way. AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization(for: .individual)
My report extension entilements
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.family-controls</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

